# Preventing mutually recursive default methods from looping at runtime

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I've currently got a structure like the following:

```
class F a where
   f :: ...
   default f :: (G a...) => ...
   f = (some definition in terms of g)

class F a => G a where
   g :: ...
   default g :: (C a...) => ...
   g = (some definition in terms of f)
```

In hopefully somewhat plain English, I can write `f` in terms of `g` always. I can write `g` in terms of `f` sometimes, namely when `a` satisfies a `C` constraint.

The issue I see here is if someone writes, for say a type `T` satisfying `C T`

```
instance F T
instance G T
```

This will compile and loop at runtime. Whilst both default definitions are correct, it's important at least one is defined.

I could solve this with a `MINIMAL` pragma if `f` and `g` were in the same class, but in this case they're not.

Also placing both `f` and `g` in the same class doesn't seem to be possible, as whilst there is a definition of `f` for every definition of `g`, there is not a definition of `g` for every definition of `f`. One possibility is moving `g` into `F` but also putting a `C a` constraint on it, but that would stop me from defining `g` with a non-default definition for any `a` which doesn't satisfy `C a`.

Is there any way to reorganise this to solve this dilemma I'm facing?

Comment: Another fallback option would be not to have a default definition of `g` and/or `f`, but to instead provide a standalone function that instance-writers can use to *explicitly* opt-in to the "default" implementation (by writing `g = defaultG`). Hopefully at least make it a little harder to *accidentally* leave both as default, since at least one was a deliberate choice.

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer was nonsense, so instead here is a (hopefully) better one. This will at least give you a warning at compile time. Trick is to implement `f'` or `g` in class `G` if both `a` has instances for both `F` and `G`, but only `f` if instance of `G` is impossible.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}

class C a where

class F a where
  f :: a -> a
  default f :: (G a) => a -> a
  f = g

class F a => G a where
  {-# MINIMAL (f'|g) #-}

  f' :: a -> a
  f' = f

  g :: a -> a
  default g :: (C a) => a -> a
  g = f'

instance F Integer where
  f = succ

instance F Int
instance G Int where
  g = succ

instance C Float
instance F Float
instance G Float where
  f' = succ

-- This will give a compile time warning, but will still
-- loop at runtime:
instance C Double
instance F Double
instance G Double
```